# Нужна помощь python

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет, я пишу ботя для тг и у меня есть одна проблемка, почему-то не виводиться переменная в сообщении, можете посказать в чем проблема? КОД:

```
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Вдарити Квіза!':
            ++Rep
            stii = open('E:\Coding\Stickers_TG\sticker.webp', 'rb')
            bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, stii)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Так йому і треба, бий його!!!!\nТвоя репутація: ', Rep)
```

Переменная Rep должна била добавиться +1 и вивестись в сообщении но она впринципе не виводиться, вместо нее пустое место в сообщении.

Comment: Нет операции `++` в Питоне.  Используйте `+= 1`. Если `Rep` глобальная переменная, то объявите её глобальной: `global Rep`.

Comment: всеравно ошибки и не работает. Я пишу global Repl потом Repl = 0 потом в def lalala пишу Repl +=1 но появляются ошибки и не работает..

Comment: Покажите ошибки. И код целиком.

Comment: Одним словом я понял в чем проблема на не знаю как пофиксить, проблема в том что я не могу создать глобальную переменную, если делаю global Rep, и потом в функции пишу Rep +=1 пишет Unresolved reference 'Rep'

Comment: Вы её не определили на глобальном уровне. Вот и ошибка.

Comment: я по разному пробовал, все равно не виходит

Comment: Покажите полный самодостаточный пример, опишите желаемое поведение, опишите ошибку (всё это нужно поместить в вопрос) и вам помогут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы указали rep отдельным параметром, так можно делать только в print. Надо в конец вашей строки добавить пробел и заменить запятую перед rep на плюс.